# how to show bitmap over panel asp.net

Tags: .net, controls

How to show bitmap over panel in .Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really imagine that you even tried doing this yourself before asking the question...

If I add a `Panel` control to my Web Form, and then examine the properties of that control in the Properties Window, I see one that looks particularly interesting: the [`BackImageUrl` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.backimageurl.aspx).

Visual Studio tells me that this allows me to set:

> The background image of the panel.

By setting that property to the URL of a bitmap of my choice, I can show a bitmap over a panel in .NET.

Comment: - Thanks :). I did not notify it.